# parameters' number of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters

Does someone know how this is possible.

```
function test(a){
   console.log(a);
}
test("param1","param2");
```

I have no problem with, but I'm curius.

Comment: That's because JavaScript doesn't care if you pass more arguments...

Comment: Please point out what exactly "is possible". We can guess, but maybe you're wondering about something entirely different.